# Masking performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-graphics, core-animation

I'm creating an animation that uncovers the underlying image. There's a virtual shape (e.g. star) moving chaotically and uncovering different parts of the image.

So I had two bitmaps so far:

- mask (trace of a shape moving here'n'there)
- image (underlying image)

So far in every `drawRect()` I was:

1. creating a newMask bitmap by copying the current mask
2. drawing a stamp on a newMask
3. creating a resulting bitmap (apply newMask onto an image)
4. drawing a resulting bitmap to screen context

I'm struggling with performance in this approach. Any ideas how to improve it?

In particular:

- Is it possible to skip step 1. & 2. and draw onto mask directly (rather than clone it).
- Should I start experimenting with CALayer approach (if this kind of masking is at all possible there)
- Should I use OpenGL
- Is there any other approach to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not manipulate bitmaps. That is likely to be very CPU-intensive as well as jerky (not smooth animation.)

Instead you should use a CAShapeLayer as a mask and Core Animation.

With a shape layer you can install a path (a CGPath, which can be created easily from a UIBezierPath) into the layer. Then you create a CABasicAnimation that switches the path to a new path. The trick is to always keep the same number and type of control points in the starting and ending paths of the animation. (If the number and/or type of control points in the two paths are different you get very, very strange results. Note that the path calls that create arcs of circles actually generate different numbers of control points based on how much of a circle your arc covers, so circle arcs require special handling.)

I have a sample project on Github that demonstrates various Core Animation techniques, including a demonstration of a "clock wipe" animation that reveals/hides and image view much like you describe.

https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo

The animation looks like this:

[image]

Note that the jerky nature of that image is because it's a GIF. The actual animation on a device is buttery-smooth. It's also possible to create very complex smooth animations like this one:

[image]

(That isn't a mask animation but it could be.)

Comment: Thanks, the problem I'm having here is that shape, e.g. star is cloned - imagine 100 stars placed on a line with 1px distance, each star overlaps with the neighbor. So this can't really be done with approach you described If I understand. The shape is actually not a start, but more sth like this: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-G1PLzaN4rOs/TYrq7Pxg9UI/AAAAAAAACpE/_wuvaUoxF-E/s1600/brush.png with alpha channel